# Issue with Running Total Still

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum

I still have an issue with working out the best way to calculate a running balance.

I am going to be using this code in a Rent Statement that I am going to produce in SSRS, but the problem I am having is that I can't seem to work out how to achieve a running balance.

```
    SELECT rt.TransactionId,
       rt.TransactionDate,
       rt.PostingDate,
       rt.AccountId,
       rt.TotalValue,
       rab.ClosingBalance,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY rt.AccountId ORDER BY rt.PostingDate desc) AS row,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY rt.AccountId ORDER BY rt.PostingDate desc) = 1
            THEN ISNULL(rab.ClosingBalance,0)
            ELSE 0 end

FROM RentTransactions rt
--all accounts for the specific agreement
INNER JOIN (select raa.AccountId
            from RentAgreementEpisode rae
            inner join RentAgreementAccount raa on raa.AgreementEpisodeId = rae.AgreementEpisodeId
            where rae.AgreementId=1981
           ) ij on ij.AccountId = rt.AccountId
LEFT JOIN RentBalance rab on rab.AccountId = rt.AccountId AND rt.PostingDate BETWEEN rab.BalanceFromDate AND isnull(rab.BalanceToDate,dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

What this gives me are the below results- I have included the results below -

[image]

So my code is sorting my transactions in the order I want and also is row numbering them in the correct order as well.

Where the Row Number is 1 - I need it to pull back the balance on that account at that point in time, which is what I am doing....BUT I am then unsure how I then get my code to start subtracting the proceeding row  - so in this case The current figure of 1118.58 would need the Total Value in Row 2 = 91.65 subtracted from it - so the running balance for row 2 would be 1026.93 and so on...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SSRS has its own running total function. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I don't see how that will work as the first transaction listed needs to link off to my RentBalance tale to list the balance of the account at that particular time.

Comment: can you provide table definition and dummy data ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all the transactions being returned in your query you can calculate a running total using the `over` clause, you just need to start at the beginning of your dataset rather than working backwards from your current balance:

```
declare @t table(d date,v decimal(10,2));
insert into @t values ('20170101',10),('20170102',20),('20170103',30),('20170104',40),('20170105',50),('20170106',60),('20170107',70),('20170108',80),('20170109',90);

    select *
            ,sum(v) over (order by d
                          rows between unbounded preceding
                                   and current row
                         ) as RunningTotal
    from @t
    order by d desc
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------+--------------+
|     d      |   v   | RunningTotal |
+------------+-------+--------------+
| 2017-01-09 | 90.00 |       450.00 |
| 2017-01-08 | 80.00 |       360.00 |
| 2017-01-07 | 70.00 |       280.00 |
| 2017-01-06 | 60.00 |       210.00 |
| 2017-01-05 | 50.00 |       150.00 |
| 2017-01-04 | 40.00 |       100.00 |
| 2017-01-03 | 30.00 |        60.00 |
| 2017-01-02 | 20.00 |        30.00 |
| 2017-01-01 | 10.00 |        10.00 |
+------------+-------+--------------+
```